# Adding hide event to qtip breaks show

Tags: qtip2

I am using [qtip](http://qtip2.com/) to show a small popup and I have found that if I add a hide event as well as a show, then the show event no longer works.

Here is an example that shows a working and a broken version
http://jsfiddle.net/39mz295b/

```
<input id="works" type="text" value="Hover here - works"/>
<input id="broken" type="text" value="Hover here - broken"/>

$('#works').qtip({
    content: {
        text: 'hello'
    },
    show: {
        event: 'click mouseenter'
    }/*,
    hide: {
        event: 'click mouseleave'
    }*/
});

$('#broken').qtip({
    content: {
        text: 'hello'
    },
    show: {
        event: 'click mouseenter'
    },
    hide: {
        event: 'click mouseleave'
    }
});
```

Interestingly, if I just have a single event on both show and hide it also works.

```
$('#broken').qtip({
    content: {
        text: 'hello'
    },
    show: {
        event: 'mouseenter'
    },
    hide: {
        event: 'mouseleave'
    }
});
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting rid of the hide event seems to fix the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/refqzkpx/

```
$('#fixed').qtip({
content: {
    text: 'hello'
},
show: {
    event: 'click mouseenter'
},
hide: {
    /*event: 'click mouseleave'*/
}
```

Comment: No an answer as to why it doesn't work with a hide event list but this works for what I need. Thanks